# How to putform data into json file in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I want to put form data into JSON file after submitting and validating form. I am getting the object but I can put it. Here is my code.

```
onAddSubmit() {
    const data = {
        institution: this.institution,
        degree: this.degree,
        year: this.year
    }
    addData(data) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post('./data.json', data, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work magically, you would need to configure a /data.json endpoint on your server and write appropriate server side logic to create or update a file when the endpoint receives a post request.

Comment: You cannot write directly to a file using a client-side framework like Angular 2. You can create a small server in something like NodeJS, create a route that accepts an object, and then write it out using the server. Look at something like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033357/angular2-http-post-to-local-json-file

Comment: Thank you for your answers I understand what you say, so I have an another question how can I push it.

Comment: @Erik, what do you mean *push it*? You can't add data to a json file like this :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already solve this problem

Comment: @Erik Can you please let me know how did you push data to local data.json since I am searching for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Way I do is covert data into json using

`const body = JSON.stringify(data);`

before adding it to request content