# POST request to a local json file using HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have one `json` file named **fake.json** inside assets in my angular application. Path of this file is like this.

> MyApp => src => assets => json => fake.json

I want to make a `POST` request to this file using HttpClient in my component which is in inside app folder.

> MyApp => src => app => Statistics => statistics.component.ts

Component source code

```
export class StatisticsComponent {

  persons: Person[];

  options = {
    sDom: 'rt<"bottom"p>',
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 10,
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
      this.http
        .post<DataTablesResponse>(
          './../../assets/json/fake.json',
          dataTablesParameters, {}
        ).subscribe(resp => {
          this.persons = resp.data;
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
            recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
            data: []
          });
        });
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "firstName" },
      { data: "lastName" }
    ]
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

}

class Person {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

class DataTablesResponse {
  data: any[];
  draw: number;
  recordsFiltered: number;
  recordsTotal: number;
}
```

I occurred this following error

**HttpErrorResponse Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/json/fake.json: 404 Not Found**

I got 2 doubts over this.

1. Is it valid to make a `POST` request to a local json file using Http or HttpClient. (Till now I have done `GET` request using Http not HttpClient and got the data successfully)
2. Why it returns 404 Not Found when the file is present there inside the folder.

Need Help.

Comment: please check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033357/angular2-http-post-to-local-json-file

Comment: Which version of `angular-cli` do you use?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Angular CLI version 1.6.1

Answer (score 5):

It's because whatever you put inside `assets` folder will be served via `GET` requests. You can test this by simply navigation to `http://localhost:4200/assets/json/fake.json` on browser. If you want to test `POST` method, you need to start a server.

`HttpModule` is deprecated and removed in later versions of Angular. You should change it to `HttpClientModule`

To test it with `HttpClient`, you can do the following.

Add `HttpClientModule` to your `AppModule`

Inject `HttpClient` within your component

`constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}`

And make the request as follows

```
this.httpClient.get('/assets/json/fake.json',  { observe: 'body' })
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to read or write data from a local JSON file, you can use json-server.

1. Create fake.json file.
2. Install json-server `npm i json-server`.
3. Start the JSON Server `json-server --watch fake.json`.
4. Now request the server on `http://localhost:3000/`

Follow the documentation link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server